# Unable to store and retrieve data from LiteDb

Tags: c#, .net, litedb

I am trying to write one object to LiteDb and read it back.
I have tried following code but somehow all parameters of LiteDbParamEntry object are returned as NULL or zero.

```
public class LiteDbParamEntry
{
    [BsonId]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return (Index * 0x100) + SubIndex; }
    }

    public ushort Index;

    public ushort SubIndex;

    public string Text;
}

public class LiteDbParamValueStorage
{
    private const string _liteDbPath = "MyLiteData.db";

    public LiteDbParamValueStorage()
    {
        WriteEntry(123, 25);
        ReadEntry(123, 25);
    }

    public void WriteEntry(ushort index, ushort subIndex)
    {
        using (var db = new LiteDatabase(_liteDbPath))
        {
            var entry = new LiteDbParamEntry {Index = index, SubIndex = subIndex, Text = "SomeText"};

            var entries = db.GetCollection<LiteDbParamEntry>("LiteDbParamEntry");

            entries.Insert(entry);
        }
    }

    public void ReadEntry(ushort index, ushort subIndex)
    {
        using (var db = new LiteDatabase(_liteDbPath))
        {
            var collection = db.GetCollection<LiteDbParamEntry>("LiteDbParamEntry");
            var paramEntry = collection.FindById((index * 0x100) + subIndex);
            if (paramEntry != null)
                Console.WriteLine(paramEntry.Text);          //paramEntry.Text is returned as Null
            else
                return;
        }
    }
}
```

Can somebody please point me in right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, i've found what's wrong with your code... You forgot to add `{ get; set; }` instruction on the right side of field declaration ;)

Take a look here:

```
public class LiteDbParamEntry
{
    [BsonId]
    public int Id
    {
        get { return (Index * 0x100) + SubIndex; }
    }

    public ushort Index { get; set; } //getter/setter added

    public ushort SubIndex  { get; set; } //getter/setter added

    public string Text  { get; set; } //getter/setter added
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! Adding getter/setter and decorating `Index`, `SubIndex`, `Text` with `[BsonField]` attribute fixed my issue.

Comment: If you want keep Fields, you can set `BsonMapper.Global.IncludeFields = true;` before open database.